# keeping score against computer in separate function(c++)

Tags: c++

I need help with scorekeeping. I've been racking my brain trying to figure it out. Where I am mainly seem to be stuck is running the score() function for whether the user or the computer and having it update the score value back to the user, and printing it. Not only that, but running the code ends up with the program only rolling the random number every other roll and checking the loops if the user wins, loses, or ties. Appreciate any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>  //random number generator
#include <ctime>  //random number generator
using namespace std;

//Programmer defined functions
void introduction(string obj, string ins);  //introduction
int computerPlay();
int userPlay();
int score(int x);
void cpuHandCheck();

//main program
int main()
{
    //Data
    srand(time(0));  //initialize random number generator
    string objective = "play the game of rock, paper, scissors."; //program objective
    string instructions = "Try and beat the computer at rock, paper, scissors!";

    int cpuHand;
    int userHand;
    int computerScore = 0;
    int userScore = 0;

    introduction(objective, instructions);  //introduction
    cpuHandCheck();



}//main

    void introduction(string obj, string ins)
    {
        //data
        //obj is the program objective
        //ins is the user instructions, if any

        //output the user introduction
        cout << "Objective: This program will ";
        cout << obj << endl;
        cout << "Programmer: \n";
        cout << "Editor(s) used: Notepad\n";
        cout << "Compiler(s) used: TDM MinGW\n";
        cout << "File: " << __FILE__ << endl;
        cout << "Complied: " << __DATE__ << " at " << __TIME__ << endl;
        cout << ins << endl << endl;

    }//introduction

    void cpuHandCheck()
    {
        while (!userPlay() == 0)
        {
            int userHand = userPlay(); //inputs user hand
            int cpuHand = computerPlay();  //generates computer hand
            if (cpuHand == 1)  //checks if they computer rolled 1=rock
            {
                if (userHand == 1)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Rock.\n";
                    cout << "Tie!\n";
                }
                else if (userHand == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Rock.\n";
                    cout << "You Win!\n";
                    score(userScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
                else if (userHand == 3)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Rock.\n";
                    cout << "You Lose!\n";
                    score(computerScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
            }
            else if (cpuHand == 2)  //checks if computer rolled 2 = paper
            {
                if (userHand == 1)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Paper.\n";
                    cout << "You lose!\n";
                    score(computerScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
                else if (userHand == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Paper.\n";
                    cout << "Tie!\n";
                }
                else if (userHand == 3)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Paper.\n";
                    cout << "You Win!\n";
                    score(userScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
            }
            else if (cpuHand == 3)  //checks if computer rolled 3 = scissors
            {
                if (userHand == 1)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Scissors.\n";
                    cout << "You Win!\n";
                    score(userScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
                else if (userHand == 2)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Scissors.\n";
                    cout << "You lose!\n";
                    score(computerScore);
                    cout << "Your score: " << userScore << '\n';
                    cout << "Computer score: " << computerScore << '\n';
                }
                else if (userHand == 3)
                {
                    cout << "Computer chose Scissors.\n";
                    cout << "Tie!\n";
                }
            }

        }
    }//cpuHandCheck
    int userPlay()
    {
        cout << "Choose: [1=rock, 2=paper, 3=scissors, or 0 to quit]: ";
        int input;
        cin >> input;

        if (input == 1)
            cout << "You chose Rock.\n";
        else if (input == 2)
            cout << "You chose Paper.\n";
        else if (input == 3)
            cout << "You chose Scissors.\n";
        else if (input == 0)
            cout << "Thanks for playing!";

        return input;
    }//userPlay

    int computerPlay()
    {
        int cpuHand = 1 + rand() % 3;
        return cpuHand;
    }//computerPlay

    int score(int x)
    {
        return x++;
    }//score
```

Comment: Just a style thing, but it seems more natural to say `while (userPlay() != 0)` instead of `while (!userPlay() == 0)`. As to your problem, you return the updated score but ignore the return value of the function so it never changes. You could either try `userScore = score(userScore);` or make the parameter a reference `void score(int& x)` and don't return the value since the reference will be modified directly.

Comment: Also you call userPlay() twice on a row, once in the while() condition and when you assign userHand.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you guys. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

So you seem to be struggling with two things that beginners often struggle with, returning values from functions and the increment operators. Here's the correct code for `score`

```
int score(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}//score
```

Your version of `score` used the post increment operator, which increments the variable but what you want to do is return a score one more than the value passed into the function. So simple addition is all you need for that, there's no need to increment the variable in the function.

And secondly you don't get the new score unless you assign to the score variable in your `cpuHandCheck` function, so

```
userScore = score(userScore);
```

not

```
score(userScore);
```

Your version calls the score function but then does nothing with the returned value.

Both your mistakes indicate that in your mental model C++ uses *pass by reference*, the function score gets a reference to one of the variables in `cpuHandCheck`, and can use that reference to modify the original variable.

But that is not true. By default C++ uses *pass by value*, functions receive values not references, The values they receive are **copies** of the values in the original variables, and changing the copy obviously has no effect on the original variable.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate your help. I definitely need to hit the books more since I cant seem to find any reference to this stuff in my notes.